# The minimal number of messages required to solve the mutual exclusion problem in a symmetric distributed system

Tags: lower-bounds, dc.distributed-comp

In [the seminal paper introducing their namesake algorithm for solving the mutual exclusion problem in a distributed system](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/358527.358537), Ricart and Agrawala assert (in the first paragraph of section 4 *Message Traffic*, on p. 13) that in a system comprising $N$ nodes the number of inter-node messages that their algorithm requires in order to allow an arbitrary node to enter its critical section is $2*(N-1)$, and that this number is the theoretically minimal one possible for any symmetric distributed mutual-exclusion algorithm when the nodes act independently and concurrently.

They explain why this number is the theoretically minimal possible as follows (section 4.1 *Concurrent Processing*, on p. 13):

> For a symmetrical, fully distributed algorithm there
> must be at least one message into and one message out
> of each node. If no message enters/leaves some node,
> that node must not have been necessary to the algorithm;
> then the algorithm is not symmetrical or is not fully
> distributed. Furthermore, to allow the algorithm to operate concurrently at all nodes, the messages entering
> nodes must not wait for the message generated at the
> conclusion of processing at other nodes. This would
> indicate that two separate messages per node are required. The requesting node does not need to send and
> receive messages to itself, however, and so a total of
> $2*(N - 1)$ messages are needed. This number must be
> a minimum for any parallel, symmetric, distributed algorithm.

I don't understand the argument. Could you please explain it to me? Is there a way to formalize the argument? I believe I will understand the argument better if it is presented formally.